# how to reverse the URL of a ViewSet's custom action in django restframework

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework

I have defined a custom action for a ViewSet

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False, permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny]) 
    def gender(self, request):
        ....
```

And the viewset is registered to url in the conventional way

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include                                          

from rest_framework import routers                                                 
from api import views                                                              


router = routers.DefaultRouter()                                                   
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet, base_name='myuser')                   

urlpatterns = [                                                                    
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),                                               
]
```

The URL `/api/users/gender/` works. But I don't know how to get it using `reverse` in unit test. (I can surely hard code this URL, but it'll be nice to get it from code)

According to the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse), the following code should work

```
reverse('admin:app_list', kwargs={'app_label': 'auth'})
# '/admin/auth/'
```

But I tried the following and they don't work

```
reverse('myuser-list', kwargs={'app_label':'gender'})
# errors out
reverse('myuser-list', args=('gender',))
# '/api/users.gender'
```

In the [django-restframework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#reversing-action-urls), there is a function called `reverse_action`. However, my attempts didn't work

```
from api.views import UserViewSet
a = UserViewSet()
a.reverse_action('gender') # error out
from django.http import HttpRequest
req = HttpRequest()
req.method = 'GET'
a.reverse_action('gender', request=req)  # still error out
```

What is the proper way to reverse the URL of that action?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `reverse` just add to viewset's basename action:

```
reverse('myuser-gender')
```

See [related part](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions) of docs.

Comment: You may need to add the application name: `reverse('api:myuser-gender')`

Comment: @A.J. Example in [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#reversing-action-urls): `view.reverse_action('set-password', args=['1'])`

Comment: May I add, you will need to use 'gender-something' if function name is gender_something

Comment: if your action consists of 2 words separated by "_" then in `reverse` you need to place a "-" instead

Comment: Like @MatthewHegarty pointed out, you may need to also add the app namespace. You can save time by running `python manage.py show_urls` first and find the URL name from there if you are debugging.

Comment: Just so nobody gets confused, the handy `show_urls` command is part of [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions), not Django core.

Answer (score 30):

You can print all reversible url names of a given `router` at startup with the `get_urls()` method

In urls.py after the last item is registered to the `router = DefaultRouter()` variable, you can add:

```
#router = routers.DefaultRouter()
#router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
#...
import pprint
pprint.pprint(router.get_urls())
```

The next time your app is initialized it will print to stdout something like

```
[<RegexURLPattern user-list ^users/$>,
 <RegexURLPattern user-list ^users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>,
 <RegexURLPattern user-detail ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$>,
 <RegexURLPattern user-detail ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>,         
#...
]
```

where 'user-list' and 'user-detail' are the names that can be given to `reverse(...)`

Comment: Why there is a dot afters users/pk, shouldn't it be '/'? 
<RegexURLPattern user-detail ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>

Answer (score 1):

Based on [DRF Doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#reversing-action-urls).

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

view = UserViewSet()
view.basename = router.get_default_basename(UserViewSet)
view.request = None
```

or you can set request if you want.

```
view.request = req
```

In the end, you can get a reverse action URL and use it.

```
url = view.reverse_action('gender', args=[])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `UserViewset().reverse_action()` specifically, you can do this by assigning a  `basename` and `request = None` to your ViewSet:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    basename = 'user'
    request = None

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False, permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny]) 
    def gender(self, request):
        ....
```

and in urls.py:

```
router.register('user', UserViewSet, basename=UserViewSet.basename)
```

Then calling `url = UserViewset().reverse_action('gender')` or `url = UserViewset().reverse_action(UserViewSet().gender.url_name)` will return the correct url.

**Edit:**
Above method only works when calling `reverse_action()` only once because the `ViewSetMixin.as_view()` method overrides `basename` on instantiation. This can be solved by adding a custom subclass of `GenericViewSet` (or `ModelViewSet` if preferred) like so:

```
from django.utils.decorators import classonlymethod
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet

class ReversibleViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    basename = None
    request = None

    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, actions=None, **initkwargs):
        basename = cls.basename
        view = super().as_view(actions, **initkwargs)
        cls.basename = basename
        return view
```

and subclassing this class for the specific ViewSets, setting basename as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `reverse('myuser-gender')`.

**Note!** But remember that DRF will replace `_` in the action name with `-`. That means if the action name is `my_pretty_action` in the reverse you should use `reverse(app-my-pretty-action)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you would like to get the list of users you use

```
reverse("myuser-list")
```

details

```
reverse("myuser-detail",kwargs={"id":1})
```

In here you might notice i use list or detail by adding it to the reverse so if you add appname you can just input it  thats because we are using viewsets