# Django DRF router reverse with kwargs

Tags: django, router, reverse

```
class API(ModelViewSet):

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'], )
    def invite_users(self, request, pk=None):
        chat_group = self.get_object()
        

invite_users_url = reverse('group-detail', kwargs={'pk':group_id, 'format':'invite_users'},)
```

---

I want  `path/pk/invite_users` but I got

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'group-detail' with keyword arguments 
'{'pk': 'SvY9aA1SK6ok', 'format': 'invite_users'}
```

Comment: Share the `urls.py`.

Comment: router.register(r'chatgroups', ChatGroupsAPI, basename='group')

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51317608/11544538) will help, in your case it would be `reverse('group-invite-users', ...)`